# Uploading files using ftplib in python

Tags: python, ftplib

Using "ftplib" Python package, I connect to a host, post which I send a binary file using "storbinary: function to this directory. However, the file transfer does not happen, the source file is over-written and made 0 bytes

Tried using "cwd" within ftplib to change to destination directory before uploading file.
Tried 'rsync' on the command line which works fine (thus establishing file integrity).

```
print ('Establishing FTP connection')
ftp = FTP(dest_dir, 'user', 'password')
print '+++++', ftp.pwd()   
ftp.cwd(dest_dir)
print 'work dir now', ftp.pwd() 
ftp.retrlines('LIST') 
f_name = /home/test/file_to_upload
with open(f_name, 'rb') as cfile:
    ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % f_name, cfile)
ftp.quit()
```

The file: /home/test/file_to_upload should be uploaded to dest_dir, instead it is getting over-written and also becomes an empty file, i.e. file contents are erased

Comment: I am not sure, but you are calling storbinary with f_name = /home/test/file_to_upload, which is a path not a valid filename. Maybe try to hardcode the filename in storbinary to check first?

Comment: And what do you meant by "source file"? is that the file in your local system or the remote file on ftp?

Comment: f_name is single file or list of file. can you try with single file

Comment: one more thing, u are storing file into binary_mode will it possible to store into binary mode

Comment: @Tempo810 source file is in my local system. Also, hard coding file name does not work.

Comment: @user765443, f_name is a single file. Can you please explain "u are storing file into binary_mode will it possible to store into binary mode". The file is a binary file.

Comment: @user2046535 ...your local file is overwritten?! are you testing with a ftp server on same machine where source and destination are the same?

Comment: valid point, can u try with change machine

Comment: @user765443 already tried

Comment: @user2046535 have tried with different machines. The source and destination is not the same.

Comment: can u try with text file just want to make sure if it is binary file issue or not

Comment: tried that as well

Comment: so it is working file. only issue with binary file am i right?.can you type also. python >>import ftplit  >> print ftplib.__file__

Answer (score 0):

f_name contains directory of your local system. Try to extract the filename only. Also be careful adding a space between ‘STOR’ and ‘filename’

**Example:**

```
ftp.storbinary('STOR '+ os.path.basename(f_name), open(f_name, 'rb'))
```